# How to generate a list of random numbers with many zero values in Python?

Tags: python, random

I want to add two list of random numbers in python. The first list is constructed with hundred random values. The second list should have only 4 or 5 random values and the rest of them should be 0. Then I want to add up these two list:

```
import random

#generating signal
signal = [10 * random.uniform(0,1) for i in range(100)]
peak = [100 * random.uniform(0,1) for i in range(100)] # something like [0 0 97.64 0 0 0 78.45 0 0 ... 0 24.26 0 ... 0]
result = signal + peak
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: How + the topic in the header+ ?   --thanks for mentioning, I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this with `random.shuffle`:

```
peak = [100 * random.uniform(0,1) for i in range(5)] + [0] * 95
random.shuffle(peak)
```

```
>>> peak
[0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 91.11950003988669,
 0,
...
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0.5653008974595974,
 0]
```